# How to build json string from list var

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to construct some JSON to use in an Ansible uri POST task.  I have a list of "tags":

```
ok: [testserver] => {
    "post_tags": [
        "st_unclass_app", 
        "st_test_app"
    ]
}
```

And I need to create a string of JSON for the body of a POST method for a uri task.  The tags list makes up a part of the full string, so I need to construct a fact that is the string for the section of the overall JSON code. 
 The string should come out looking like the following:

```
{"tag": "st_unclass_app"}, {"tag": "st_test_app"}
```

My issue is two-fold: 1) The number of tags will vary, so I need to make this dynamic in length. and 2) The string is constructed with JSON-relevant characters, and I know I will have to navigate that.

I've not been able to find any helpful hints anywhere so far, but am still looking.  Searching for things like "concatenate string to list," etc isn't returning anything useful.

Here's the static task I need to complete

```
  - name: Apply tags
      uri:
        url: https://{{ nsxt_host }}/api/v1/fabric/virtual-machines?action=update_tags
        method: POST
        user: "{{ nsxt_user }}"
        password: "{{ nsxt_pass }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
          Accept: :application/json,version=2
        body: {"external_id": '{{ nsxt_record.json.results[0].external_id }}', "tags": [{"tag": "st_unclass_app"}, {"tag": "st_test_app"}]}
        body_format: json
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I'm expecting it to look something like this:

```
  - name: Apply tags
      uri:
        url: https://{{ nsxt_host }}/api/v1/fabric/virtual-machines?action=update_tags
        method: POST
        user: "{{ nsxt_user }}"
        password: "{{ nsxt_pass }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
          Accept: :application/json,version=2
        body: {"external_id": '{{ nsxt_record.json.results[0].external_id }}', "tags": ['{{ nsxt_tags }}']}
        body_format: json
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, using join and escaping double-quotes.  Here is the task to construct the JSON:

```
- name: Build tag string
      set_fact:
        nsxt_tags: "{\"tag\": \" {{ post_tags | join('\"}, {\"tag\": \"') }} \"}"
```

And here is the update uri task:

```
- name: Apply tags
      uri:
        url: https://{{ nsxt_host }}/api/v1/fabric/virtual-machines?action=update_tags
        method: POST
        user: "{{ nsxt_user }}"
        password: "{{ nsxt_pass }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
          Accept: :application/json,version=2
        body: {"external_id": '{{ nsxt_record.json.results[0].external_id }}', "tags": '{{ nsxt_tags }}'}
        body_format: json
      delegate_to: localhost
```